# converting date format

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to convert date in a format 2011-08-17 to Wed, 17 Aug 2011
we are using the following format

```
<input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" class="calendarSelector" 
    value="<?php print date("D, d M Y"); ?>" />
$day1 = $this->input->post('date1');
```

But value got is 2011-08-17
How to convert it using php?

Comment: if you read that data from user's input, be ready to get any data in any format.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=converting+date+format+php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
date("D, j M Y", strtotime(date1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by converting the value mentioned to a Unix timestamp and then formatting it using the standard date command.

```
<?php
echo date("D, j M Y", strtotime($day1));
?>
```